# How to get Django queryset in Ajax conform data structure?

Tags: python, django

I have a view that transforms a queryset into a list which is then returned as JSON for further use of [Ajax autocmplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) on client-side. However, since I need multiple fields (namely poller_text and poller_id) of each object Ajax requires the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "value": "poller_text",
        "label": "poller_text",
        "url": "poller_id"
    },
    {
        "value": "poller_text",
        "label": "poller_text",
        "url": "poller_id"
    },
]
```

Right now this is what I get using the view below:

```
["poller_text", "poller_id", "poller_text", "poller_id"]
```

```
# View

def autocomplete(request):
    if 'term' in request.GET:

        qs = Poller.objects.filter(poller_text__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
        pollers = list()

        for poller in qs:
            pollers.append(poller.poller_text)
            pollers.append(poller.poller_id)

        return JsonResponse(pollers, safe=False)

    else:
        pass
```

I think the append loop is badly designed, but how to get the required structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append dictionaries, so with:

```
qs = Poller.objects.filter(poller_text__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
pollers = [
    {'url': poller.poller_id, 'value': poller.poller_text, 'label': poller.poller_text}
    for poller in qs
]
return JsonResponse(pollers, safe=False)
```

for a UUID object, you can use `str(…)` to convert it to a string that contains only the UUID:

```
qs = Poller.objects.filter(poller_text__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
pollers = [
    {'url': str(poller.poller_id), 'value': poller.poller_text, 'label': poller.poller_text}
    for poller in qs
]
return JsonResponse(pollers, safe=False)
```

You can define a truncate function to limit the length of the `poller_text` to 30:

```
def trun_poller_text(mystr):
    if len(mystr) > 30:
        return f'{mystr}…'
    else:
        return mystr
```

and then use this in the view function:

```
qs = Poller.objects.filter(poller_text__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
pollers = [
    {'url': str(poller.poller_id), 'value': trunc_poller_Text(poller.poller_text), 'label': trunc_poller_Text(poller.poller_text)}
    for poller in qs
]
return JsonResponse(pollers, safe=False)
```

---

> **Note**: In 2008, [Phil Haack discovered a way to obtain data from the outer JSON array](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/).
> While most browser have implemented countermeasures, it is still better to use a
> JSON object as "envelope" of the data. That is why a
> [**`JsonResponse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)
> by default does not allow something else than a `dict` as outer object. It might
> thus better to wrap the data in a dictionary and keep `safe=True` on `True`.

Comment: it returns `'url': UUID('2ca99330-423b-497e-ab78-248a711268d2'),` for the url. Any chance to get rid of the UUID part to get `'url': '2ca99330-423b-497e-ab78-248a711268d2'`?

Comment: Use `str(poller.poller_id)` instead of `poller.poller_id`.

Comment: if you by any chance notice this comment, how would I slice `poller_text` by [:30] so that the dict only contains poller texts with max 30 chars? In the list loop or at some other stage?

Comment: @Jonas: what should happen if the commit is longer? *Omit* the entry, or *truncate* the `poller_text`

Comment: if text is longer than 30, I'd like to return the first 30 chars + '...' because I run into issues on the client side.

Comment: three dots (`...`) or an ellipsis (`…`)?

Comment: ellipsis would be awesome

Comment: @Jonas: see the edit, the last two code fragments specify a way to truncate it, and one to use that function to truncate the `poller_text`.